# How to post data to API in jQuery DataTable ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

Hi all I am using jQuery DataTable and performing server-side pagination and sorting.
I am stuck at one place, I am having API that is of type POST, so I need to send my payload in Body.

I tried `POST` method in ajax but it kept throwing `415` status code i.e  payload `format is in an unsupported format`. I have noticed that my payload is getting sent in form data.
How can I resolve this issue?

**Here is my code** -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#dataTable').DataTable({
        columns: [
            { "data": "FirstName" },
            { "data": "LastName" },
            { "data": "PhoneNumber" },
            { "data": "Address1" },
            { "data": "Email" },
            { "data": "Fax" },
            { "data": "Calls" },
            { "data": "Address2" },
            { "data": "Deal status" },
            { "data": "Conversations" }
        ],
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "ajax":{
            "url": "myAPI",
            "dataType": 'application/json',
            "type": "POST",
            "beforeSend": function(xhr) {
                xhr.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Bearer Token");
            },
            "data": function (d) {
                d.status= "Active";
                d.field = "";
                d.order="asc";
            },
            dataFilter: function(data) {
                var json = jQuery.parseJSON( data );
                json.recordsTotal = json.totalElements;
                json.recordsFiltered = json.totalElements;
                json.data = json.content;
                console.log("total data",json);
                return JSON.stringify( json ); // return JSON string
            }
        }
    });
});
```

How can I resolve this 415 status code and send payload correctly?
Please Help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are non returning anything from the:

```
"data": function (d) {
    d.status = "Active";
    d.field = "";
    d.order = "asc";
},
```

so, according to the [docs](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.data) for the `ajax.data` option:

> If there is no return value from the function (i.e. `undefined`) then
> **the original data object passed into the function by DataTables will
> be used for the request** (the function may have manipulated its
> values).
>
> If an object is returned, then that object will be used as the data
> for the request. It will not be merged with the original data object
> constructed by DataTables before being sent.

Try:

```
"data": function (d) {
    const extraPayload = {};
    extraPayload.status= "Active";
    extraPayload.field = "";
    extraPayload.order="asc";

    return {...d, ...extraPayload}
},
```